# Vec2Word neural network scheme

Tags: matlab, word-embedding

Could someone describe the probable deep network scheme for the function vec2word in Matlab? I'm just wondering which type of neural net should be used in order to convert a vector to a word? Or in other words, reverse word embedding. Any help highly appreciated.